# Magento contact us custom transactional email: Customer received plain html codes

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email, cms

I have created a custom transactional email for contact us and applied this on the admin contact. The emails are successfully received on our test email. However, the email contains all the html codes. I have tried my best to solved this but I can't do it. I also tries to research for similar problem but no luck. I am using magento 1.9.1.0 version.

this is my transactional email code

```
<!doctype html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Hey</tile>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <tr>Name:</tr>
            <tr>{{var data.name}}</tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

this is what we received in the email

```
<!doctype html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Hey</tile>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <tr>Name:</tr>
            <tr>Simon</tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I solve this issue? Is there any settings on the admin that I did not enabled?

I hope you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe late for an answer...

Make sure your config.xml contains such a line : `<type>html</type>`.

```
   <template>
        <email>
            <Your_node_here translate="label" module="your_module_name">
                <label>Your Label here</label>
                <file>dir/file.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </Your_node_here>
        </email>
    </template>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Don't include `<head>` section.

```
<!doctype html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Hey</tile>
</head>
```

That's all I could see default transactional email not having them. For transactional email magento by default adds `<head>` for you. **So whatever you add in template will be treated as email content.**

**Update**

Replace your code with this:

```
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <tr>Name:</tr>
            <tr>Simon</tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

You need  tag to tell browser this is `html`.

**Update 2**

Replace above code in `your_email_template.html` as well as in `transactional email template` (System > Transactional Email) if you have created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to remove those tag and retain the table tag and other html tag however I still receive it as it is. Still no change.

Comment: Have you deleted </html> at the end too? All you keeping is <body> to </body> only.

Comment: Yes, actually my first code starts on the table tag only. I tried to add the html, head and meta hoping it will work. But still no luck. It's like the system interpret the code as all pure text.

Comment: You have to wrap your table inside **<body></body>**, that's why it is not getting called as html.

Comment: I tried to wrapped the table inside body tag however still the same. I suspect that this is not about the tags but I suspect that there something else to be configure in the system. the problem is that I don't know where

Comment: Can you confirm you haven't created new "Transactional email" template or if you have then editing there. Some time we forget.

Comment: Yes I created a new transactional email for my custom contact us page. I received all the data that the user inputted however those data are literary  enclosed in an html tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25476/discussion-between-adarsh-khatri-and-rodge).

Answer (score 1):

Following are steps to create custom Template emails. Make sure you have followed them:

1. Go to **System** > **Transaction Emails**
2. Click on **Add new Template**
3. Under "**Load default template**" which is first tab, for "**Template**" select "**Contact Form**" and Click on "**Load Template**"

[image]

This should load a default template

4. Now add your custom details under tab "**Template Information**":
   for "**Template Content**" you can fill

> ```
> <body> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
>     <tr>
>         <td>
>             <tr>Name:</tr>
>             <tr>Simon</tr>
>         </td>
>     </tr> </table> </body>
> ```

Click on "**Preview Template**"  and make sure the template looks like how you want it to look.
[image]

Click on "**Save Template**" once satisfied. This should give you whats desired.

**UPDATE**:
IF this isnt working:
@Rodge maybe give this a try:

Copy: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Email/Template/preview.php

To: app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Email/Template/preview.php

> Comment (Line:63):
>
> //$template->setTemplateText(
>              $filter->filter($template->getTemplateText())
>          );

Test this for Preview Transaction Emails in admin panel, and see if this works.

Comment: Hello Joshua. When I click preview it display all the tags same as in email.

Comment: @Rodge I updated my answer. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I can't find the line of codes that you have mentioned.

Comment: Line no 63:

 $template->setTemplateText(
            $filter->filter($template->getTemplateText())
        );

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I tried to comment out line 63 but still preview doesn't display what I want. Also, I received on my email all my codes/tags